# Display timezone name in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to display Timezone name while displaying date and time, I managed to display date time:

my code:

```
Carbon\Carbon::parse($notes->created_at)->format('F d Y H:i:s')
```

> May 31 2018 18:50:08

I wanna display like:

> May 31 2018 18:50:08 +GMTxxx

How do i do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `e` flag will do what you are asking:

> `e` | Timezone identifier (added in PHP 5.1.0) | Examples: UTC, GMT, Atlantic/Azores

**Live Example**

[Repl](https://repl.it/repls/TemptingQuarterlyFrontend)

**Reading Material**

[`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)